# Getting NSSet data to populate table view

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a Todo app with a one-to-many relationship. The data model is the following:

```
Todo Lists {
    listName: String
    todos: NSSets
}

Todos{
    todoName: String
    list: (not sure but points back to the Todo List)
}
```

In my entry table view I have fetched all of my Todo Lists and populated the table view. Now when I click on a Todo List I want to `prepareForSegue` with the Todo List pressed and then populate the Todos table view with all the todos associated with the Todo List clicked. I am not sure how to fetch the todos associated with the Todo List clicked and pass it to the next view controller with prepare for segue.

Comment: Don't use NSSet, it doesn't guarantee that data is ordered, as side effect your table view with todos may show wrong data. If you like Set features you can use NSOrderedSet.

Answer (score 0):

**Q: I am not sure how to fetch the todos associated with the Todo List clicked and pass it to the next view controller with prepare for segue.**

If on the `Todo` data structure you have the list which it belongs to, you can:

1 - Pass the list to the "list detail view controller";

2 - The list detail view controller will fetch the Todos for that list;

I thought like this because in this case I don't want to load the all the `Todo`s for all my `TodoList`s, since the user may never even open a list and I can save some memory. This way you have to do something like:

```
struct Todo {
    let id: String // unique
    let name: String
    let list: TodoList
}

struct TodoList {
    let id: String // unique
    let name: String
}

class TodoListDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var list: TodoList {
        didSet {
            todos = fetchTodos(from: list)
        }
    }

    private var todos: [Todo]! {
        disSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // Your code.......
}
```

You'd set the `list` variable on your `prepareForSegue` before showing the `TodoListDetailViewController`.

It's importante to say that I don't know how you're dealing with the relation between each data so I assumed you're using a `String` id.